# missing Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

By WS2008 i did a Report using SSRS Report Server (.RDL file) to show data from an SQL Olap Cube and all work fine.

Now i want embed this report in a web page (.ASPX) with Asp.Net (IIS 7) by the **Microsoft Report Viewer** (i'd installed already the version 8 and 9).

To do that i have to add some rows in the `Web.Config` to use the http handlers to view the report.

Something like that:

```
<add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd"
type = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms,
 Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

As you see the `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler` is requested but isnt installed in the server as picture below

[image: list of assembly installed]

So what i have to install to have this handler installed in the server ?

What is missing or i am misunderstanding in this topic ?

Thanks in advance for who can help me in this

Comment: Are you using IIS 6 or IIS 7 to serve the .aspx page?

Comment: @ Eric Brenden - IIS 7 is installed on the server but if you speak about to add an Handler Mappings, in the combo box you cant find the item because is missing the Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HttpHandler doesn't need to be installed separately - it's part of the report viewer control.  The config entry you have is for IIS 6.  If you are using IIS 7, it should be in the `<system.webServer>` section:

```
<handlers>
    <add name ="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</handlers>
```

You will need to remove the other config entry for this to work correctly.  Also, there is a [version 10 of Microsoft Report Viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442) available.  I've had problems when multiple versions of the dlls are installed so I would try to just use 10 and remove versions 8 and 9.